# How can I go about serving single page html using node.js on port 80?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My project structure looks like this:

- project

  - assets/images/
  - css/application.css
  - js/application.js
  - font
  - node_modules
  - index.html
  - server.js
  - package.json

My goal is to be able to run 'node server.js" in the project folder and have it serve on port 80. Going to localhost:80 or w.e would render the index.html along with its css/assets/js.

I've tried with connect, express and http but no luck...new to node.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

First of all, change your structure:

- project

  - assets/images/
  - assets/css/application.css
  - assets/js/application.js
  - assets/font
  - node_modules
  - views/index.html
  - server.js
  - package.json

First require some packages:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path');
```

Them run in the terminal window:

```
npm install express
```

Them set up the configurations:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // This is to serve static files like html in the views folder
app.set('view engine', html); // your engine, you can use html, jade, ejs, vash, etc
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80); // set up the port to be production or 80.
app.set('env', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'); 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'))); // // This is to serve static files like .css and .js, images, fonts in the assets folder
```

Them create your routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello word');
});

app.get('/something', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hei, this is something!!!');
});
```

If you want render the index, inside the views folder:

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

And finally:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(req, res) {
 console.log('Server listening at ' + app.get('port')');
});
```

Them access localhost:80/index

Comment: Thanks for this! Its exactly what I needed. However when running 'node server.js' I recieve this error. Its one ive gotten before and never figured out./Users//Projects/thing/server.js:6
app.set('view engine', html); // your engine, you can use html, jade, ejs, vas
                       ^
ReferenceError: html is not defined

Comment: First change index.html to index.ejs, them run npm install ejs. Them in the top of the file, require ejs, var ejs = require('ejs'); finally change the 'html' in the view engine to 'ejs'.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. Getting this error. Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)

Comment: Can you take a screenshoot and upload in the imgur and post here? I am in the shopping, is hard help you in the iphone haha

Comment: Did you install and require EJS??

Comment: Here you go http://i.imgur.com/9fM9VpN.png and yes i did install and require ejs. i even did npm install ejs -g and npm install ejs --save

Comment: I am sorry, i want see the code in the server.js, are you in a mac or in a windows??

Comment: http://imgur.com/on9xpa0 i use a mac. i also changed to port 3000 since port 80 throws an error about access. ill have to figure that out later.

Comment: App.set('view engine', 'ejs'); i forgot the quotes here.

Comment: Great that fixed it, thanks! I've run into another error ive previously seen. Which is the static assets throwing a 404. im using this in my index.ejs  so i think im linking correctly...<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/application.css" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Tale off the ../assets, you dont need this part because you already explicit define with app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));

Comment: I'm glad i help you. Good luck with your project .

Answer (score 1):

Put your assets and subdirs under ./public, then from top dir, add app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('Server running...');
});
```